# Reflecting 4d symmetric data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, comsol

I've found out that there is no example of how to reflect symmetric 4d data, which **can be very useful when 3d simulations wants to be performed using a symmetric plane** to reduce calculations(e.g. ANSYS, COMSOL, etc). This example shows a data file structure corresponding to a COMSOL simulation, which has the structure: X, Y, Z, Amplitude

The model had a symmetry along the Y-plane and was sliced on this plane, so less mesh elements must be calculated. In order to obtain a full Y-plane view (i.e. Y from -0.5 to 0.5), the data has to be reflected along the Y plane.

An example code for such a problem would look like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

### generate a SIMULATION type-file###
X = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 50)
Y = np.linspace(-0.5, 0, 50)    #to be reflected/extended to 0.5
Z = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 50)
Xq, Yq, Zq = np.meshgrid(X, Y, Z)
Amp = 1* np.exp(-((Xq - 0) ** 2 / (0.03) + ( Yq - 0) ** 2 / (0.03) + ( Zq - 0) ** 2 / (0.03)))

datafile = np.vstack([Xq.ravel(), Yq.ravel(), Zq.ravel(), Amp.ravel()]).T   #resemble the simulation data structur, in this case X, Y, Z, Amp

### PYTHON POST-PROCESSING ###
X = datafile[:, 0]
Y = datafile[:, 1]
Z = datafile[:, 2]
Amp = datafile[:, 3]    #Amplitude could be a Pressure, Force, Magnetic field, etc

xq = 0.0    #choose an arbitrary plane to show amplitude distribution over this plane
yq = np.linspace(min(Y), max(Y), 50)  
zq = np.linspace(min(Z), max(Z), 50)
Xq, Yq, Zq = np.meshgrid(xq, yq, zq)
int_plane = griddata((X, Y, Z), Amp, (Xq, Yq, Zq), method='linear')
int_plane = np.squeeze(int_plane)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(Zq, Yq, zs=int_plane)
ax.set_title('3D view');
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()
```

[image]
An important detail to have in consideration, is that the plane Y=0 must not be duplicated.

**The purpose here is to reconstruct the other half of the dataset** (i.e. the whole other 3D half space + corresponding amplitudes). A correct reflection of the 3D space would output then a full 3D Gaussian. How could this be efficiently accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reflect along the *y* axis, omitting the last element, and append the reflected data to  data itself

```
amp = np.vstack((amp, amp[-2::-1]))
```

Example:

```
In [37]: x, y, z = (-1, 0, 1), (-50, 0), (-5, 0, 5)
    ...: X, Y, X = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)
    ...: data = X+Y+Z
    ...: print("----------------", data, sep='\n')
    ...: data = np.vstack((data, data[-2::-1]))
    ...: print("----------------", data, sep='\n')
----------------
[[[-56 -50 -44]
  [-56 -50 -44]
  [-56 -50 -44]]

 [[ -6   0   6]
  [ -6   0   6]
  [ -6   0   6]]]
----------------
[[[-56 -50 -44]
  [-56 -50 -44]
  [-56 -50 -44]]

 [[ -6   0   6]
  [ -6   0   6]
  [ -6   0   6]]

 [[-56 -50 -44]
  [-56 -50 -44]
  [-56 -50 -44]]]

In [38]:
```

Comment: That's a great answer!. Just a small detail, the Y axis has to go from -0.5 till 0.5 and not from -0.5 back to -0.5, or in your example from -50 to 50. :)

Comment: @DesperateMorty `vstack((Y,-Y[-2::-1]))`